# Magento Attribute with the same code already exists

Tags: magento-2.1, customer-attribute

I am trying to get a new Magento 2.1 store configured, but I have an issue when I try to save the Customer Configuration, where I get the warning: Attribute with the same code already exists.

I thought it was to do with a specific attribute I was changing to start with, but I get the same error without making any changes and just hitting Save on this admin page. No other pages cause me this issue.

How do I find out which attributes are causing the problem here? And how do I resolve the issue?

I'm guessing that something is a little messed up from the data import migration from my Magento 1.9 store, but I had no part of that migration, so not sure where to start checking for issues?

I see nothing helpful in any of the log files to point me to a solution.

Comment: @robogt have you tried clear the magento cache?

Comment: Yes, many many times through the development of my new site :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turned out that the data migration had caused some issues. The company that migrated the data for me have resolved this.